# PHP Auto Login to Webmail (Rainloop) with stored Password

Tags: php, autologin, webmail

I am programming a platform, where the user has a profile and separately gets an E-Mail address.
In this platform they can store some settings and their E-Mail Password.
Now they can click on "login webmail",
Rainloop opens in new popup, and they are already logged in.

So I now I have to solve security issues:

I don't want to save the password as plain text in my portal database.
Rainloop provides following example for autologin.

```
<?php
$_ENV['RAINLOOP_INCLUDE_AS_API'] = true;
include '/var/www/rainloop/index.php';
$ssoHash = \RainLoop\Api::GetUserSsoHash('user@yourdomain.com', 'plain-password');
\header('Location: http://yourdomain.com/rainloop/?sso&hash='.$ssoHash);
```

What would be a secure way to encrypt the plain password before saving it to database, and decrypt it in the script which generates the ssoHash

Comment: If you need the raw password later which it sounds like you do to generate the hash, then encryption isn't your answer as it's a 1 way street.

Comment: So there are 2 seperate account, one normal user account and one explicitly for email, which you both own?

Comment: @TobiasF. Yes, you can use the E-Mail account without Webmail. Webmail is just an extra service. But it is annoying to Login to Portal, then again to Webmail. The Password is stored only for webmail login. And Rainloop needs plain password for generating ssohash

Comment: @Ian isnt hashing one way? And not encryption

Comment: @BYil You are correct, encryption is 2 way whereas hashing isn't, apologies for that. Rainloop still expects a plain password to be passed through though.

Comment: @Ian the Question is, how can encrypt the plain Passwort, store in DB and decrypt it when autologin, but in a secure way.